# Is there a way to generate a report of errors that occur in our logs during production? Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

It appears like it would be nearly impossible to read through the logs of your production application every morning searching for errors and the lines in which those errors are occurring. Is there something I can use which will automatically generate a daily report for me of any errors that occur in my application and the location of those errors. Something I can review each morning without taking up too much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest picking a service that errors can be reported to and aggregated, etc.  There are quite a few options.  I personally use errbit (free, self hosted) in conjunction with the airbrake gem (which can be configured to use it).  Or you can signup for Airbrake itself.  Or use Exceptional.io, or one of the other services.

- https://github.com/errbit/errbit
- https://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home
- http://www.exceptional.io/
- http://newrelic.com/
- https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/exception_notification